# How to set permissions efficiently

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a list of Exchanges (extract shown below) and I want to give a user WRITE permissions to all **but those containing `Invoice`** in the name. Here an extract of the list of Exchanges as an example:

```
E.BankAccount.Commands
E.BankAccount.Commands.Confirmations
E.BankAccount.Commands.Errors
E.BankAccount.Events
E.Customer.Commands
E.Customer.Commands.Confirmations
E.Customer.Commands.Errors
E.Customer.Events
E.Invoice.Commands
E.Invoice.Commands.Confirmations
E.Invoice.Commands.Errors
E.Payment.Commands
E.Payment.Commands.Confirmations
E.Payment.Commands.Errors
E.Payment.EventsEvents.test
```

So I can write a regex like this:

```
E\.(BankAccount|Customer|Payment)\.[a-zA-Z.]+
```

This works but since I have more than 100 different types it is a lot to type and almost impossible to maintain. Better would be to have a regex which **excludes** invoice. I tried a couple of things but without any look, e.g.

```
E\.([a-zA-Z.]+|?!Invoice)\.[a-zA-Z.]+     or
E\.([a-zA-Z.]+|?!(Invoice))\.[a-zA-Z.]+
```

But that is all syntactically wrong. Another strategy could be to reverse the result of the expression e.g. use

```
E\.(Invoice)\.[a-zA-Z.]+
```

and then somehow **reverse** the entire result but I could not figure out how!

I am not using regex very often so I can't find any better solution then the first one which is impracticable in my production environment.

Does anybody have more experience and a solution to that problem?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simple - don't use RabbitMQ to control permissions for your business logic. You need to have access control defined elsewhere in your application. Message layer is for communication, not authorization.

Comment: Thats not the answer to my question. You do not know my system so you should not post architectural advices!

Comment: I'm merely stating a fact. RabbitMQ was not designed to do whatever it is you are trying to do with it. If you wish to come up with a design that uses the wrong tool for the job, that's fine by me, but my understanding is that posting a question implies you'd like some insight from the software community.